# Как для столбца добавить категорию (вместо NaN)?

Tags: python, pandas

как для столбца “Балкон” добавить категорию “Отсутствует” (вместо NaN)?

```
import pandas as pd # Импортируем библиотеку обработки и анализа данных pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Импортируем модуль pyplot библиотеки matplotlib для построения графиков
import datetime                 # Импортируем модуль datetime для обработки данных в формете даты
import numpy as np              # Импортируем библиотеку numpy
#from google.colab import files  # Импортируем библиотеку files для работы с файлами
import re                       # Регулярные выражения

lab = pd.read_csv('moscow.csv', sep = ';')
lab = lab.query("Комнат != 'Для заметок:'") #Удалить для заметок
lab = lab.drop(columns=['ГРМ','Примечание'],axis=1,inplace=True)# Удалить колонки ГРМ и Примечание
lab ['Балкон']= lab ['Балкон'].fillna('отсутствует')

print (lab.head())
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
lab ['Балкон']= lab ['Балкон'].fillna('отсутствует') 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Да, так можно. А что смущает?

Comment: lab ['Балкон']= lab ['Балкон'].fillna('отсутствует')
                    ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Приведите в вопросе ваш код начиная с создания фрейма

Answer (score 1):

```
lab = lab.drop(columns=['ГРМ','Примечание'],axis=1,inplace=True)
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Вызов методов `Pandas` с параметром `inplace=True` производит операции "по месту" и возвращает `None`. Этот параметр будет удалён в будущих версиях, лучше никогда его просто не используйте:

```
lab = lab.drop(columns=['ГРМ','Примечание'],axis=1)
```